# Mark edges using mouse pointer

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to manually mark edges in an image to create ground truths to compare to my own implementations of edge detection algorithms to construct ROC curves.

Is this possible in Matlab, I've used 'roipoly' before so I know there are some functions which let you select regions in an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matlab function `ginput` to capture the clicks of the user, and then build something around that.

Otherwise, you can use the **Label me Toolbox**:

http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/LabelMeToolbox/index.html

[image]

You can also use `imcrop`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'll check out both methods.